# Is It possible to get a BEEP sound in Linux using the GCC compiler?

Tags: c, linux, beep

Is there any way to play the BEEP sound when I write the following program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{printf("\a");
}
```

I tried running the program using the GCC compiler in Linux but it did not give any beep whereas when the program ran in the Windows Environment, it generated the system default beep.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the compiler. It's about what your hardware and terminal support.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep

Comment: Please replace whatever book told you to use `void main()`; it was written by someone who doesn't know the language very well. The correct definition is `int main(void)`. (`void main()` might happen to work, but it's neither portable nor correct.)

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C file and command line tool that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct; the program generates a beep-signal.
I suppose, that a beep signal switched off in your terminal.
May be you have enabled visual-bell.
In this case your terminal must blink.

Comment: Umm, I do no get any visual blinking of the Terminal in Ubuntu. Could you please tell me how to enable the beep sound in the Terminal then?

Comment: @PranavJituri: It depends on the terminal-emulator. You can start for example xterm and enable visual bell in it (hold `ctrl` then click and drag the mouse wheel; you will see a menu, in that you must choose "Enable visual bell")